# Fastapi form data from Bootstrap 5 Switch box

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi, bootstrap-5

I want to use a Switch box from Bootstrap 5:

```
<div class="form-check form-switch">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="yes_no" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckDefault">Yes</label>
</div>
```

It works when the Switch button is 'On' or `True`, but when it is 'Off', I get the following error in the console:

```
"?[1mPOST /form HTTP/1.1?[0m" ?[31m422 Unprocessable Entity?[0m
```

And this in the frontend:

```
{"detail":[{"loc":["body","yes_no"],"msg":"field required","type":"value_error.missing"}]}
```

Tried with an `if/else` statement in Python:

```
@app.post("/form")
def form_post(request: Request,
              yes_no: bool = Form(...)):
    if yes_no:
        print(yes_no)
    else:
        print("No")
    return templates.TemplateResponse("form_response.html", 
                                      context={'request':request}
```

But I still get the same error. I also tried other things like `yes_no:str = Form(...)` but still the same error.

Output I want is the value 'Yes' if the toggle is 'On' or `True` and the value of 'No' if the value is 'Off' or `False`.

Comment: I'd think giving a default value should work: `yes_no: bool = Form(False)`?

Comment: It was that simple huh :D. Thanks MatsLindh, if you want you can post an answer and I will gladly accept it. Would be good also for the future ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the value to be optional, provide a default value:

```
@app.post("/form")
def form_post(request: Request,
              yes_no: bool = Form(False)):
```